# Merging and transforming specific rows in Dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to merge and transform specific cells in a dataframe in R.

```
asd <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A"),Col2 = c("B"),Col3 = c("C"),Col4 = c(1),Col5 = c(2),Col6 = c(3), Col7 = c("Z"))
asd
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7
1    A    B    C    1    2    3    Z
```

Something like below

Expected output (Basically Col4, Col5 and Col6 are answers to Questions Col1, Col2 and Col3 respectively). Last column (Col7) should be merged into 1 cell

```
asd
Val     Col1 Col2 Col3 Col7

Ques    A    B    C  
                       Z
Ans     1    2    3
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4K76.png]

Comment: What do you mean by *"Last column (Col7) should be merged into 1 cell"*? Can you please provide the expected output in code form (i.e. as a call to `data.frame`)?

Comment: Yes your right. Like it belongs to both 1 and 2 row. So need to merged

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output in code form (i.e. as a call to data.frame)?

Comment: The problem i am not able to frame like a dataframe. I have edited my question. PLease refer :)

Comment: So what do you want? As you realized yourself, you can't have something like *merged cells* in a R data.frame...

Comment: So wanted to check if we can achieve this or not. Since I could not able to resolve this